# How to delete NetworkImageView cache?

Tags: android, reload, android-volley, networkimageview

remove(IMAGE_URL);Im trying to make an app what display picture from livecamera in NetworkImageView from volley, the picture of URL im using is changing like every 5 seconds so I have made an reload button witch call a method to delete cache of that URL and then load IMG from that URL again. The IMG is first time loaded when app is started.

But the problem is that the image is not changing, also I dont see any delay in loading that image after I click reload button(ussualy it takes about second to load IMG) what I think mean that its still loading that IMG from chache not from Internet.

This is what is in my logcat after calling method .remove(IMAGE_URL);

```
3947-3947/com.example.alex.livecam D/Volley﹕ [1] DiskBasedCache.remove: Could not delete cache entry for key=http://meteo.profi-net.sk/webcams/BIELAPUT-l.jpg, filename=16357443311577153225
```

This is the code Im using to reload IMG:

```
    public void reload() {
    AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(IMAGE_URL);

    mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);
    mImageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader);
}
```

Any advice?